# Stuck threads with RestTemplate despite read timeout and connection timeout

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, connection-timeout, socket-timeout-exception

I am using Spring's `RestTemplate` and the HTTP factory I am using with it is `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

I was experiencing many stuck threads while making HTTP calls because of issues with called-server. So, I configured read timeout as well as connection timeout with my `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

This helped but only upto an extend, now I see that instead of all threads being stuck right away at least some initial number of threads timeout successfully, but I noticed that after a point of time again my threads are stuck with the HTTP call.

Here are my questions:

- Since I am having both read and connection timeout, any thoughts on why I am still getting threads stuck on RestTemplate based HTTP call?
- My own thought is that request is getting lost in the network, I know it is theoretically possible but is it practically possible in my case?
- I searched and found out that I can set `sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout` and `sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout` at JVM level, since I am already using timeouts with my `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` will it have any meaningful impact?

Any other thoughts or recommendations on how I can solve this issue would be appreciated.

---

Code is in a VM so this is the best I can do:

[image]

Comment: It would probably help if you could show us the code involving `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and setting the timeout values.

Comment: @CryptoFool: Done, please check.

Comment: @pjj hi, looks like I have the same issue. I have Spring Boot application that calls a set of different services usinf RestTemplate. One of those service is ElasticSearch. For some reason I have periodically stuck calls, which end in timeout exceptions. But if I do calls with curl I have 100% success. Any luck with the issue?

Comment: @Dmytro: Nops..

Comment: Hi pjj, I can confirm problem was either in apache's HttpClient or HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory of Spring. After change to SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory which uses java.net.HttpURLConnection and checking in production for few month, I can confirm that I had no timeout errors